# Java regex to replace all special characters in a String with an underscore also considering removing leading,trailing,multiple underscores

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I would need a regular expression to replace all the special characters considering multiple with a single underscore and also not to add trailing and leading underscore if the String contains trailing and leading special characters, I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
String myDefaultString = "_@##%Default__$*_123_"
myDefaultString.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]", "_")
```

My eventual result should be `Default_123` where the regular expression needs to consider leading underscore and remove them keeping the underscore in between `Default` and `123` but also should remove trailing and multiple underscores in between the String.

Also tried the following regex

```
myDefaultString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "_")
```

But does not seem to work, is what I'm trying to achieve very complicated or it there a better way to do it?

Comment: What do you consider `special characters`? Could you please give some examples of inputs and expected outcomes? Thanks.

Comment: Alternative, emphasizing readability: str = str.replaceAll("[\\W_]+", " ").trim().replaceFirst("\\s", "_");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex in `replaceAll`:

```
String str = "_@##%Default__$*_123_";
str = str.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]+|^_+|\\p{Punct}+(?=_|$)", "");
//=> "Default_123"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dcceuE/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]+`: Match 1+ punctuation characters that are not `_`
- `|`: OR
- `^_+`: Match 1+ underscores at start
- `|`: OR
- `\\p{Punct}+(?=_|$)`: Match 1+ punctuation characters if that is followed by a `_` or end of string.

Comment: Go 1337: Change `(?!_)[\\p{Punct}]` to`[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]`

Comment: Yes `[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]` will surely work. I just cannot use it on regex101

Comment: Yes I have modified my answer. It will be bit more efficient to use `+` after `[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]` as well

Comment: Oh yes. I retract my square bracket suggestion: I didn't notice the `+`. btw I never use regex101 - I find it noisy and it's also completely unusable on a mobile device. I use  [rubular](https://rubular.com/r/oUqEb1w2pghyBp) instead. It understands java/POSIX  regex.